# Static block in intent service throws NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, static, intentservice

have created a `IntentService`, in which I have created a static block in which I am doing some net related work, On which it is giving `NetworkOnMainThreadException`:
**Code** looks like :

```
public class XService extends IntentService {
    static {
        //Net related work 
        //on executing this gives NetworkOnMainThreadException
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //Doing my work here
    }   
}
```

How can this `throw NetworkOnMainThreadException` when `IntentSrevice` run on separate thread?

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Only the  onHandleIntent() callback runs on a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are doing a network operation on the main thread, and this is not allowed on Android 3.0 and above. Even though it is in a service, services are run on the UI thread unless you specifically launch them in another thread or create a thread inside it.

You can fix this by running the task in a service off the main UI thread, by using a Thread or an `AsyncTask`.

Try creating a new thread in `onStartCommand()`

Or you can do something like...

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() { 
@Override public void run() {
 getData(); 
} });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the net related work you want to do inside `OnHandleIntent()` as this method runs on a separate thread.

Where you are putting the net related work now runs on the main thread.